# How to exclude InfoBarMessageControl in Orchestra Shell MahApps?

Tags: mahapps.metro, catel, orchestra

I'm building an application using the Orchestra MahApps shell (built on Catel), but would like to exclude the InfoBarMessageControl. It seems there is an option in the Catel DataWindow constructor to set the generation field, but it doesn't appear this option is exposed in the ShellWindow constructor. What would be the proper method for disabling (`InfoBarMessageControlGenerationMode.None`) while using the MahApps shell?

Also listed on https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/discussions/542, but I'm not sure if anyone checks there.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I think it's not possible out of the box. For now a workaround would be to use private reflection to set this field using this pseudo code:

```
var field = GetType().GetFieldEx("_infoBarMessageControlGenerationMode");
field.SetValue(this, InfoBarMessageControlGenerationMode.None);
```

Make sure to call this code *before* `OnInitialized` is called the WPF.